# Office Js: Outlook Addin dialogue api not working in outlook client

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to login with gmail using dialogue API.

For outlook web its get authenticated successfully. I got a payload.

But, when i try to login in outlook client with the same implementation i didn't get any response from dialogue event.

manifest.xml

```
<AppDomains>   
<AppDomain>https://my.website.com</AppDomain>
```

```
 Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, options,
        (asyncResult) => {
          let dialog = asyncResult.value;
          dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, (arg) => {
            if (arg.message.type == 'SSO_AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS') {
}
```

dialogue.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="javascript">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Paperflite Add-in</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        var redirectUrl = urlParams.get('redirectUrl');
        window.location.href = redirectUrl;
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you observe is expected. DialogEventReceived only returns built-in events listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-handle-errors-events#errors-and-events-in-the-dialog-box